# How to skip empty lines when copying files with Gradle?

Tags: filter, copy, gradle

I would like to copy some files in Gradle and the resulting files should not contain any blank lines, i.e., the blank lines are not copied. I assume that can be done with `filter(...)` and maybe with the `TokenFilter` from ant. However, I am not sure how to the syntax would look like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle uses [Ant for filtering](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html), because of its powerful implementation. For example, you can use the [LineContainsRegExp](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/LineContainsRegExp.html) Ant filter to filter out any line that is only empty or whitespaces.

The appropriate regexp can be `[^ \n\t\r]+`

You can use Ant directly from Gradle like this:

```groovy
task copyTheAntWay {
  ant.copy(file:'input.txt', tofile:'output.txt', overwrite:true) {
    filterchain {
      filterreader(classname:'org.apache.tools.ant.filters.LineContainsRegExp') {
        param(type:'regexp', value:'[^ \n\t\r]+')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or by using the [Gradle CopySpec's](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html) filter method:

```groovy
task copyGradlefied(type:Copy) {
  def regexp = new org.apache.tools.ant.types.RegularExpression()
  regexp.pattern = '[^ \n\t\r]+'
  
  from(projectDir) {
    include 'input.txt'
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.LineContainsRegExp, regexps:[regexp])
  }
  into "outputDir"
}
```

Comment: How did you know to do regexps as an array? My best reading of the documentation concluded the param would be simply regexp: 'my-regex'.