# Gradle copy task - null pointer when filtering closure returns null

Tags: groovy, ant, gradle

The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:filter(groovy.lang.Closure)) states that if I return `null` from closure the line should be removed, however when I do this

```
filter { String line ->
    line.startsWith('-') ? null : line
}
```

I get this

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.LineFilter.getTransformedLine(LineFilter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.LineFilter.ensureData(LineFilter.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.LineFilter.read(LineFilter.java:83)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.LineFilter.read(LineFilter.java:93)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReaderInputStream.read(ReaderInputStream.java:117)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyFile(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:74)
... 90 more
```

Note that if I put an empty string instead of null it leaves an empty line. So 1) why is it not working as documented? 2) If I am doing smth wrong how can make this filter work?

Just in case (using wrapper):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-05-05 08:09:24 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     5c9c3bc20ca1c281ac7972643f1e2d190f2c943c

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
JVM:          1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64
```

Comment: Have you tried returning nothing? instead of null

Comment: Note that if I put an empty string instead of null it leaves an empty line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:filter%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) of your version, 2.4 I mean, not the current one, which is the latest and 2.7 at the moment. It contains just:

> Adds a content filter based on the provided closure. The Closure will be called with each line (stripped of line endings) and should return a String to replace the line.

No word about null. So, it seems, that this behaviour was added in the newest versions. Due to javadocs, it was introduced since version 2.6.

If you need it to be working, you have to use a newer version or use a custom Ant based task, like it was mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954089/4053652) with the regex you need.